# Opening tab-delimited text file in Excel mangles special symbols

Tags: excel, text, encoding, import

I have a tab-delimited text file which contains dagger characters (`†`). When I open this in Excel 2010, they are mangled and replaced with `â€`  (I'm not sure if Excel is adding the space, too). Why does this occur and how can I fix it?

Right now I do search and replacing in Excel to replace the `â€` s, but it's inefficient for many files and hacky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original file is not using the character encoding that Excel expects.

See

[Character Encoding and the â€™ Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421316/character-encoding-and-the-a-issue)

Excel's Import Wizard is better at handling encoding issues and may be able to open your source file properly.  See

[Microsoft Excel mangles Diacritics in .csv files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155097/microsoft-excel-mangles-diacritics-in-csv-files)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, after taking another look at [Open .csv file containing special characters in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529287/open-csv-file-containing-special-characters-in-excel) I realized that instead of Right Click -> Open with Excel, if I go to File -> Open in Excel it lets me choose the encoding.